# How to write the fancy O

Tags: letters

[image: Fancy O]

I thought this is italic theta. I tried `\textit{\theta}`, `\textit{$\mathcal{O}$}` . But, I couldn't get this letter.

Comment: That's `\mathscr{O}` with `\usepackage{mathrsfs}`.

Comment: @campa Thank you so much!